# How do i write this simple sql statement involving joins?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

Categories table:

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| cat_id          | int(8)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| cat_name        | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| cat_description | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| cat_order       | int(8)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Topics table:

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| topic_id      | int(8)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| topic_subject | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| topic_date    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| topic_cat     | int(8)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| topic_by      | int(8)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

topic_cat corresponds to cat_id in a foreign key relationship.

How can i write an sql statement which returns: The NEWEST topic from every category plus the category name???

Heres what i have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM categories 
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT topic_id, topic_subject, max(topic_date) AS MaxDate, topic_cat, topic_by 
   FROM topics 
   GROUP BY topic_subject) AS mt 
ON categories.cat_id = mt.topic_cat 
ORDER BY cat_order;
```

It returns multiple topics from the same category, where i only want one topic per category.

Comment: You're nearly there. Basically, you missed a (couple of) join condition(s). And you don't need an OUTER JOIN. An INNER JOIN will suffice (I think)

Comment: You group by "topic_subject", why? Would not topic_cat be better?

Comment: @SamuelÅslund not really sure. Thats part of the reason i'm here haha. Could i get away with not having a group by statement at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try to get the [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group), you need to join back to the original table (`topics`) to pick the row that has the max date. Because just mentioning `MAX(topic_date)` in your subquery doesn't make the *other* columns come from the row where that max date is found. What if you also mentioned `MIN(topic_date)`?

This should be a solution (though I haven't tested it):

```
SELECT *
FROM topics AS t
JOIN (SELECT topic_cat, MAX(topic_date) AS topic_date
      FROM topics
      GROUP BY topic_cat) AS maxt USING (topic_cat, topic_date)
RIGHT JOIN categories AS c ON t.topic_cat = c.cat_id
```

Comment: Interesting! This does what i ask, thank you very much. Now for the kicker, how might i include along with that all categories which do not yet have a topic associated with it?

Comment: I added `RIGHT JOIN` above.

Comment: Ah that was simple. Thank you for the explanation in addition to the code. Its always nice to understand why something works.

Answer (score -1):

The first, easy, but not so powerfull solution would be to GROUP BY topic_cat and ORDER BY topic_date in topics select:

```
SELECT * FROM categories 
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT topic_id, topic_subject, topic_date, topic_cat, topic_by 
      FROM topics 
     ORDER BY topic_date DESC
     GROUP BY topic_cat) AS mt 
ON categories.cat_id = mt.topic_cat 
ORDER BY cat_order;
```

I think MySQL should be able to handle this, even it's not really universal solution for other database engines, where the rules for grouping are more strict.